# jackknifing blocks (*not* time series)

Tags: biostatistics, jackknife

I have the following problem.

There are 50 subjects. Each subject does a block of 100 trials. At the end I want to compute a complicated statistic s() on the data x. Now I want to be able to compute a confidence interval on this statistic, and so need an estimate of SD(s(x)).

Please let me know what you think of this idea: do a jackknife, but instead of computing s() for x[-i], i=1 to 50 (where -i means delete observation x[i]) in the usual jackknifing way, instead compute s() deleting each *subject*. Then get the SD estimate the usual way. So I'll have 50 pseudovalues instead of 5000.

The idea of this is that fundamentally, most variability in s() will be caused by subjects anyway, so it makes sense to jackknife those. And in reality it would have been impossible to miss a single x value (they were always collected in blocks of 100), but certainly possible to have a missing subject.

Thanks for any help. My google searches for "jackknife blocks" have only turned up refs relevant to time series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems what you are looking for is *delete-m (or delete-d) jackknifing*, where $m=d=100$.

<strike>What you are describing is cross validation with 50 groups, and you have made each group the 100 trials. This is a valid, although biased, estimator of your statistic $s()$.</strike>

Comment: Thanks Tommy. I have looked now at cross-validation. My impression that it works by making a prediction for the test set from the training set. I can see how this makes sense for a regression model for example. But there is nothing that I am predicting. Unless I am predicting s(x) where x is the full data set. Is that it? My s() is sort of a complicated descriptive statistic.

Comment: You are correct, this does not fit your problem exactly. What you want to do then is the "delete-m jacknkife". This is related to the bootstrap procedure. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resampling_%28statistics%29#Comparison_of_bootstrap_and_jackknife

Comment: ok thanks Tommy. I see that with delete-d jackknife I have to compute all choose(n,d) pseudovalues of the statistic, which is not feasible, since n=5000 and d=100. I don't see why this is necessary for my example. I suppose a bootstrap version could be done instead. But still I like what I originally proposed.

Comment: Also have a look at the *delete-a-group jackknife*. Perhaps that is more suited to your needs.

Comment: Thanks Tommy. It seems like I can do what I proposed originally, describe it as "delete-a-group jackknife" and cite Kott. Excellent!